# Sql -How to fetch the last 5 minutes of data

Tags: mysql, sql, dateadd

Hello I am attempting to pull the last 5 minutes of data from the database.
The query I have written below is not pulling the data I need.

```
Select e.*
  from Event e
 where e.whenoccurred >= datefunc('10/01/2019 00:00 -05:00', '-5 minutes') 
   and dateadd(minutes,-5,getdate())
```

I receive the error

```
Query has failed: no such column: minutes
```

Any ideas that can help?

Answer (score 2):

> **SysDate**
>   returns the current date and time set for the operating system on which the database resides. The datatype of the returned value is DATE, and the format returned depends on the value of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT initialization parameter. The function requires no arguments. In distributed SQL statements, this function returns the date and time set for the operating system of your local database.

this query get sysdate minus five minutes.

```
 select *
  from event
 where whenoccured >= sysdate - (5/1440)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

**[Query #1 Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c6d40cc83105508e3e27602f2cc059e)**

```
 SELECT * FROM event
 where whenoccured >= date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute);
```

**[Query #2 Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c6d40cc83105508e3e27602f2cc059e)**

```
 SELECT * FROM event
 WHERE whenoccured >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
```

**[Query #3 Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c6d40cc83105508e3e27602f2cc059e)**

```
 SELECT * FROM event
 WHERE DATE_ADD(whenoccured , INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) >= NOW();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
select *
  from event
 where whenoccured >= systimestamp - interval '5' minute
```

where `systimestamp` stands to return the current system date, including fractional seconds and time zone.

**Update** (*if MySQL DB is the case instead of Oracle initially as tagged*) use [`date_sub()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function:

```
select *
  from event
 where whenoccured >= date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute);
```

assuming `whenoccured` column is of type `datetime` or `timestamp`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=621cb435bd4c31f36460d8d4c4b1db32)</kbd>

Comment: thank you for your response but I am receiving another error Query has failed: near "'5'": syntax error

Comment: you're welcome @Xfactor, are you sure that you're using Oracle DB(tagged as so), the error (and also functions) suggests MySQL.

Comment: im sorry yes it is mysql

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server, the first parameter of **dateadd** function should written in singular. In your case, instead of "minutes" you should use "minute".

Here's a working example:

```
select getdate()

select dateadd(minute,-5,getdate())
```

For further details on **dateadd** function I would suggest you to refer to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp